# How to create dynamic arraylist and put the arraylists into hashmap?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
public HashMap viewTableData(String tabName)
   {
       ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
       ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
       ArrayList<String> arrayList3 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
       ArrayList<String> arrayList4 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
       HashMap discoverMap = new HashMap();

        try {

            con = DAOConnection.sqlconnection();
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            query = "SELECT * FROM "+tabName;
            System.out.println("Qry executed");
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = ps.executeQuery(query);


            while(rs.next())
            {

                arrayList.add(rs.getString(i));
                arrayList2.add(rs.getString(2));
                arrayList3.add(rs.getString(3));
               arrayList4.add(rs.getString(4));


            }

            discoverMap.put("qrycol1", arrayList);
            discoverMap.put("qrycol2", arrayList2);
            discoverMap.put("qrycol3", arrayList3);
            discoverMap.put("qrycol4", arrayList4);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Query.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
        return discoverMap;
   }
```

Every tables has its different column, so how to use this code for dynamic sql table?(assume, I can get the column value by some other method, number of column can be get from Information.Schema.)
Suppose, number of column store in a int value i. 
How to use loop and do this work dynamically?

Comment: ArrayList are usually dynamic

Comment: I don't think a HashMap would work for this. A HashMap only allows keys to be unique, in a database it doesn't have to be unique. You're probably better off with a SortedList and do binary searches on them. There are also In-Memory databases that you can use.

Comment: It can be done by using loop 
for(i=1;i<=4;i++){
arrayList.add(rs.getString(i));
discoverMap.put("qrycol"+i, arrayList);
}
in this case, I am getting different keys. But still problem in loop.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific like what you want to achieve and what problem in loop you are facing. where have you initialized the arraylist and Map

Comment: Please see the code, I initialised at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the looping problem that you mentioned in the comments. Try something like this. Hope it answers your question. But it would have been more helpful had you described the business scenario in more detail.

```
Map discoverMap = new HashMap();
for(int i=1; i<=4; i++){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(rs.getString(i));
    discoverMap.put("querycol"+i,list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but maybe this class (`ResultSetAdapter`) can help:

https://github.com/gk-brown/HTTP-RPC/blob/master/Server/Java/httprpc-server/src/org/httprpc/sql/ResultSetAdapter.java

It wraps a JDBC `ResultSet` instance and makes it look like a `List<Map<String, Object>>` (in other words, a list of maps). You can iterate through it like this:

```
// Iterate over rows
for (Map<String, Object> row : new ResultSetAdapter(resultSet)) {
    // Iterate over columns within current row
    for (String column : row.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(column + " = " + row.get(column));
    }
}
```

An advantage of this approach is that you don't need to copy the values from the result set into a new list or map - the adapter class simply decorates the result set, making it look like a list of maps.